# Event handlers not triggering when attached to custom list (2013 on-premises)

Tags: 2013, 2010, event-receivers, event-handlers

I have a three 2010 event handlers installed on-premises on 2013 foundation that are all part of the same solution (added, updating, updated), none of which are triggering when they are attached to the list (confirmed by SP Manager). I've tried writing to a list at the start of the code to show that it's running but failed. Additionally, I created a new 2010 solution that successfully writes to a list. The solution has been retracted and reactivated but still no luck. What could be the possible confliction(s) for these not running?

Comment: have you checked the uls logs?

Comment: ive checked the sharepoint log viewer logs but there was nothing I could find. would this be different to the 'uls' logs

Comment: did you upgrade your solution for 2013?

Comment: no its 2010. just deployed to another site and its working with sharepoint online

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the event receivers exist in one of your project features. also make sure that this feature is activated on your website. Finally try to change the scope of the feature (I don't think it will work if the scope is "Web", try to make it "Site")
P.S. You don't have to add code for testing writing to a list to show that it's running. You can just attach debugger to your IIS Worker Process (w3wp) and insert break point at the start of your code.

Comment: the feature is activated on site and subsite level, still no joy

Comment: what about the other points?

Comment: is your receiver in one of your features? you could rename your *.wsp to *.cab and check if the dll and definition is in there.

Comment: yes theyre all part of the same feature